# Phone Request Error in Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Am building a telegram ordering bot using python telegram bot and everything was working as it should but it just hangs after requesting for user location. The conversation handler is supposed to transition after location is shared successfully and request for the user's phone number.. What am I missing?

I tried changing the location request to inlinekeyboardbutton and inlineleyboardmarkup but the error still persists. Here's the full code, don't pay much attention to the indentation:

```
import os 
import time 
from dotenv import load_dotenv 
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,       ConversationHandler, CallbackContext) 
from telegram import (
    Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton,           ReplyKeyboardRemove)
from telegram.error import TimedOut

load_dotenv()

class MyTelegramBot: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN') 
        self.updater = Updater(
            self.token, use_context=True) 
        self.dp = self.updater.dispatcher

self.FIRST, self.SECOND, self.LOCATION, self.THIRD = range(4)

def start(
    self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("Start function called")
    user = update.message.from_user
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[
            [KeyboardButton("Products")],
            [KeyboardButton("Exit")]
        ],
        resize_keyboard=True,
    )

    retries = 3  # Number of retries
    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            update.message.reply_text(
                f"Hello {user.first_name}, welcome to ABC Events. How can I assist you today?",
                reply_markup=reply_markup,
            )
            return self.FIRST
        except TimedOut:
            time.sleep(2)  # Waiting for 2 seconds before retrying

    # If all retries fail, error is handled gracefully
    update.message.reply_text("Sorry, there was a delay in processing your request. Please try again later.")
    return self.FIRST

def exit(
    self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    update.message.reply_text("Thank you for visiting ABC Events. Let us know if there's anything else we can do for you.", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    return ConversationHandler.END

def products(
    self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    print("Products function called")
    items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]
    item_list = "\n".join([f"{i + 1}. {item}" for i, item in enumerate(items)])
    update.message.reply_text(f"Here are the products:\n{item_list}")

    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[[KeyboardButton(product)] for product in items] +
                [[KeyboardButton("Exit")]],  
        resize_keyboard=True,
    )
    update.message.reply_text("Please select a product or press 'Exit' to cancel:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return self.SECOND
 
def request_location(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("Request location function called")
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        [[KeyboardButton("Share Location", request_location=True)]],
        resize_keyboard=True,
        one_time_keyboard=True
    )

    update.message.reply_text("Please share your location:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return self.LOCATION

def process_location(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("Location received")
    location = update.message.location
    
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    update.message.reply_text("Thank you for sharing your location.", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return self.THIRD

def request_phone_number(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    print("Request phone number function called")
    user = update.message.from_user
    contact = update.message.contact

    if contact:
        user_data = context.user_data
        user_data['phone_number'] = contact.phone_number
        update.message.reply_text(f"Thank you! We'll contact you at {contact.phone_number} for delivery.")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(f"Sorry, we couldn't retrieve your contact information. Please type your phone number (in +254XXXXXXXXX format).")
        
    return self.FIRST

def edit_phone_number(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
 
    update.message.reply_text(f"Your current phone number is: {context.user_data.get('phone_number', 'not provided')}")
    update.message.reply_text("You can edit your phone number by sending it again (in +254XXXXXXXXX format).")

    return self.THIRD

def setup_handlers(self):
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, self.start)],
        states={
            self.FIRST: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, self.start)],
            self.SECOND: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, self.start)],
            self.LOCATION: [MessageHandler(Filters.location, self.process_location)],
            self.THIRD: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, self.request_phone_number)],
        },
        fallbacks=[],
    )

    self.dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", self.start))
    self.dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'^Exit$'), self.exit))
    self.dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'^Edit$'), self.edit_phone_number))

    self.dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.contact, self.request_phone_number))
  
    self.dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'^Products$'), self.products)],
        states={
            self.SECOND: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.request_location)],
        },
        fallbacks=[],
    ))

    self.dp.add_handler(conv_handler)

def run(self):
    self.setup_handlers()
    self.updater.start_polling()
    self.updater.idle()

if name == 'main': 
    bot = MyTelegramBot() 
    bot.run()
```

Comment: please note that the PTB team no longer provides support for versions 13.x and older. I recommend to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that in `setup_handlers()` you have set up the `self.SECOND` state to transition to the `self.request_location` function. But in the `products` function, you are returning `self.SECOND` directly, which means it will call `self.start` again instead of `self.request_location`.

Try it like this (in `setup_handlers()`):

```py
self.dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'^Products$'), self.products)],
        states={
            self.LOCATION: [MessageHandler(Filters.location, self.process_location)],
            self.THIRD: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, self.request_phone_number)],
        },
        fallbacks=[],
    ))
```

Comment: This won't work as the moment the client selects the item to order it reverts back to the start welcome message with product selection.

Comment: What happens if you change your transitions such that products() returns self.LOCATION, process_location() returns self.THIRD and request_phone_number returns ConversationHandler.END?

Comment: If I do that it requests for the location and saves it but doesn't continue to the phone request function.